# Shortcode to eliminate <p> and replace </p> with <br>

Tags: functions, filters, shortcode, the-content, customization

I have a filter that removes opening p tags and replaces closing p tags with a br tag sitewide. The client would like this filter in a shortcode that they can use only on specific portions of the site. Could the following code be adapted for use inside of a shortcode?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_p' );
function remove_p( $content ) {
    $paragraphs = array("<p>","</p>");
    $noparagraphs = array("","<br>");
    return str_replace( $paragraphs, $noparagraphs, $content );
}
```

We've tried an assortment of plugins that toggle wpautop but were not happy with the results. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the $content available to you in your remove_p function - so inside that function just look for the existence of a special string (i.e. your "shortcode"), to allow the filter to do the str_replace.  For example:

```
   if ( false !== strpos( $content, "[p-filter]") ) {
       $paragraphs = array("<p>","</p>","[p-filter]");
       $noparagraphs = array("","<br>","");
       return str_replace( $paragraphs, $noparagraphs, $content );
   }
   else
       return $content;
```

This will work as long as your client doesn't want to turn on/off your filter multiple times within a single POST object...if he does then it could still be done, but will be more complicated to implement.

Comment: Thank you C C for the assistance. Just what I was looking for.